# Loading a pickle package in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, pickle

I have saved one of my models in local using pickle (windows Python 3.6), I needed that model to run on an EC2 Linux instance (using Python 2.7) to make predictions. I had transferred the saved model from my laptop to EC2 instance using Filezilla, now when I am trying to load the model using the following code:

```
filename = 'Customer_segmentation_model_xgb_final.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 892, in load_proto
    raise ValueError, "unsupported pickle protocol: %d" % proto
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

Someone please suggest what I am doing wrong and what needs to be done.

Comment: try to write pickle with a lower protocol. pickle.dump(your_object, your_file, protocol=2). Seems you are trying to use file written for protocol 3 (python 3+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a compatibility problem, I would suggest to install the same version of Python on your server (python 3.6) since the pickle module is part of the Python standard library:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

You could also force a lower protocol when you dump initially (**EDIT**: like proposed in the comments):

```
pickle.dump(model, file, protocol=2)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps!!